# How to know if a given (infinite) set of vectors lie in the same hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose $\alpha \in [0,1]$. Let $V_{\alpha}$ be the $n$-dimensional vector whose $k$-th component is given by $\alpha^{(k-1)}(1-\alpha)^{(n-k)},\; k \in [n]$. Now let $X$ be the set of all such vectors, i.e. $X = \{V_{\alpha}: \alpha \in [0,1]\}$. Can $X$ lie in the same hyperplane passing through the origin, i.e. does there exist any $n$-dimensional vector $A$ such that $A^TV_{\alpha}=0$ for all $V_{\alpha} \in X$?

Edit: 
With reference to $A.\Gamma.$'s answer, what if $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Maybe this question is straightforward and I'm probably failing to understand something basic.

Comment: 1. Do you mean by $\alpha^{(k-1)}$ the $k-1$-th power of $\alpha$? 2. Do you consider only hyperplanes through the origin?

Comment: 1. Yes $(k-1)$-th power of $\alpha$. 2. Yes, because the criterion is that does there exist a vector $A$ such that $A^TV_{\alpha}=0$ for all $V_{\alpha} \in X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $a^{(k)}=a^k$.

1. There is no hyperplane that goes through the origin and contains all $V_\alpha$. To see that, set $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=1$ to conclude that the first and the last coordinates of $A$ are zeros. Then cancel $\alpha(1-\alpha)$ and continue in the same way to set $\alpha=0,1$. Hence, $A=0$. Formally, this step is proved by induction.
2. There is a hyperplane that contains all $V_\alpha$:
   $$
   1=(\alpha+1-\alpha)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\alpha^{k-1}(1-\alpha)^{n-k}.
   $$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. If I may ask - what if $\alpha \in (0,1)$? Should I include this part in the original question?

Comment: @Canine360 It makes no difference if $\alpha\in[0,1]$ or $\alpha\in(0,1)$ since the expression is a polynomial in $\alpha$, it is continuous at $0$ and $1$, so you can take $\lim$ as $\alpha\to 0,1$ with the same effect.

Comment: After we have done the first step by putting $\alpha = 0$ and $\alpha = 1$ as you said, and removed the first and last coordinates of $A$ because they're zeros, we're left with an expression from which we can take $\alpha(1-\alpha)$ common. But if we try to apply the same logic at this step, i.e. putting $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha =1$, then we cannot conclude anything about the expression within the brackets unlike the previous step, right? Because if $\alpha$ is either $0$ or $1$, $\alpha(1-\alpha)$ is already $0$.

Comment: In the above case do I take a sequence of $\alpha$s in $(0,1)$ and for each of the elements of this sequence say that the expression within the brackets is zero? ('Cause for each of the elements of this sequence $\alpha(1-\alpha)$ is $\neq 0$). Is this a valid argument?

Comment: @Canine360 After cancellation, you will get a polynomial expression in $\alpha$ that is equal to zero on $(0,1)$. Since a nonzero polynomial cannot have infinitely many zeros, the polynomial must be identical zero for all $\alpha,$ in particular, at $0,1$ too.

Comment: Sorry I'm probably asking too many questions - but if this is the logic we're using (A polynomial of finite degree can have infinitely many zeros only if it is the null polynomial), then can't we at the first step itself say, that $A=0$? Because $A^TV_{\alpha}$ is a polynomial in $\alpha$ which is zero for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Comment: @Canine360 We could if we knew that all the terms were linear independent. However, it is not obvious from the beginning, so we cannot rule out a case, for example, $\alpha^2-\alpha^2=0$. Polynomial is zero, but not all the terms are zeros.