# Multivariate polynomials with infinite number of zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I need to prove the following:

> Let $P(x_1,\cdots,x_r)$ be a polynomial. Then
>   $P(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r) = 0$ for all $(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r)
>  \in \mathbb{R}^r_{+}$ such that $\sum\limits^r_{j=1} \alpha_j = 1$ if
>   and only if $P(.)$ is the zero polynomial.

I think I have proven it also, using induction, with $A.\Gamma$'s help on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805121/how-to-know-if-a-given-infinite-set-of-vectors-lie-in-the-same-hyperplane/2805152?noredirect=1#comment5786019_2805152) question.

My question is, is there any existing result (perhaps involving fundamental theorem for multivariate polynomials, e.g.) from which this follows? I tried looking for it, found [Bezout's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), but not sure if and how this can be derived using it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: The wording of the above statement is not correct, as pointed out by others. I have posted a new question with the correct wording as suggested in question comments, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808331/prove-that-homogeneous-multivariate-polynomial-reduces-to-the-zero-polynomial-gi).

Comment: I rolled back the question to the first version that was already answered. If you want to ask a modified question then post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. Consider the polynomial
$$
P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_r) = (1 - \sum_j x_j)^2 \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Do you have any suggestion as to how we should modify this so that it holds? It holds for $r=2$ as we have seen here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805121/how-to-know-if-a-given-infinite-set-of-vectors-lie-in-the-same-hyperplane/2805152?noredirect=1#comment5784202_2805152

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned, the polynomial has no constant term. Would it hold then? Have modified the question accordingly.

Comment: @Canine360 : Multiply the given polynomial with $(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_r^2)$, then it does not have a constant term.

Comment: It would not be homogeneous then. I had also mentioned homogeneous but the edit has been reverted back (see comment on question). So the correct version is "A homogeneous polynomial"... (it'll have no constant term by definition). Let me start a new question as suggested. :(

Comment: Here is the new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808331/prove-that-homogeneous-multivariate-polynomial-reduces-to-the-zero-polynomial-gi

Answer (score 1):

The *if* part is obvious. For the *only if*, first notice that given any $(x_1, \dots, x_r) \in \mathbb{R}^r_{+}$, we can use the homogeneity of $P$ to establish the value of $P$ at this point: $$P(x_1, \dots, x_r)=\lambda^d P(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_r)=0,$$ where $\lambda = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^r x_i>0$, $\alpha_i = \dfrac {x_i} {\lambda} \; \forall i$ and $d$ is the degree of $P$ (assuming $P$ is nonzero).

Now, knowing that $P=0$ at the open set $\mathbb{R}^r_{+}$, we can choose some point $(u_1, \dots, u_r) \in \mathbb{R}^r_{+}$ and take any partial derivative of $P$ at this point (including mixed of any order) to find coefficients of $P$. For example, if $P$ would have the term $k x_{i_1}^{a_1} \dots x_{i_m}^{a_m}$, then $$k = \frac 1 {a_1! \dots a_m!} \frac{\partial^{a_1 + \dots + a_m}P(x_1, \dots, x_r)}{\partial x_{i_1}^{a_1} \dots \partial x_{i_m}^{a_m}} (u_1, \dots, u_r) = 0$$ because any other term, if exist, would become zero after such differentiation (here we use the homogeneity again) and value of the derivative is completely defined by values of $P$ at a small open neighbourhood of $(u_1, \dots, u_r)$.

Comment: As for the second part of the answer one could also consult  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789699/zeros-of-polynomial-over-an-infinite-field/2789760#2789760